# Editing tableview missing background color while editing on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

When I do tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true), cells indent and show the delete button as they're supposed to. However, on iPad, the places where the cell has indented, shows white instead of the background color i've set for the tableview, the cell and the view. This does not happen on iPhone

iPhone:
[image: iPhone:]

iPad:
[image: iPad:]

What could be causing this bug?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting the cell's contentView backgroundColor to clearColor in -cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just require to set background color of the cell's content view to clearColor in -cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
 [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: For swift users: cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

Note: I didn't put contentview, worked, havent tried with contentview

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting the color in the contentview. Use the cell itself. (UITableViewCells are UIViews)